# How to use Int value with specific byte length

Tags: swift

Need an Integer property 3 bytes length.

The main goal is I have structure:

```
packet {
    header: UInt8
    parameters: 3 bytes
    reserve: UInt16
}
```

Which have to be converted to **Data** 6 bytes in total!

Guys pls help how can I achive this?

Comment: What stops you from the first 3 bytes of each parameter into 3 `UInt8`s?

Comment: Actually, this value is dynamic it might contains data of 2 property UInt8 and UInt16 or three differeny UInt8 or one 3bytes value. Depends on cases. So it should be as Int but not less and not longer then 3 bytes

Comment: In that case, make `parameter` an array of `UInt8`, then write different setters for each case you described

Comment: I thought should be a way like: Int a = 0x001100; sizeOf(a) equal to 3 bytes

Comment: There's no 3-byte integer in Swift or any language that I know of